# ERROR: Service 'xx' depends on service 'yy' which is undefined

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql-db2
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'microsv'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    networks:
      mini_project:
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
  EurekaServer:
    image: eurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    restart: always
    networks:
      mini_project:
  Candidate:
    image: candidat
    ports:
      - "9097:9097"
    restart: always
    links:
      - eurekaServer    
    depends_on:
      - db
      - eurekaServer
    networks:
      mini_project:
#        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
  job:
    image: job
    ports:
      - "9098:9098"
    restart: always
    links:
      - eurekaServer
    depends_on:
      - db
      - eurekaServer
    networks:
      mini_project:
  zuulGateWay:
    image: zuul
    ports:
      - "9099:9099"
    restart: always
    links:
      - eurekaServer    
    depends_on:
      - db
      - eurekaServer
    networks:
      mini_project:
networks:
  mini_project:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  my-db:
```

Hi i didn't found any mistake with the compose file ,

Error is : ERROR: Service 'Candidate' depends on service 'eurekaServer' which is undefined.

can anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

I believe those service names are case sensitive. I've only ever used lowercase, not sure if uppercase will cause issues with DNS discovery. Therefore I'd recommend changing `EurekaServer` and `eurekaServer` to `eurekaserver` (and similar for the other service names.